# What can R "know" about the computer it is run on?

Tags: r, system

I am wondering what can R know about the hardware/system it runs on.

For example, I know that using "sessionInfo()" will uncover a few things.  But is it also possible to check what CPU/mem the computer has?  Is it possible to have some unique identifier to the computer used?

The motivation is for using R when sending a batch command to the cloud, and wondering how to access the configurations of the computers running the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a lot, see the following help pages.

```
?.Machine
?.Platform
?Sys.info
?R.version
?memory.limit
```

For the available RAM, use `memory.limit`, though this will be artificially smaller than the physical RAM for 32-bit R on a 64-bit system (for example, I'm not clear on details here so please treat this with caution):

```
memory.limit(size = NA)
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!  Regarding finding a unique i.d. of the computer currently in use.  The only way I found is to use nodename and user from  Sys.info().  Is there some other command that can detect a unique i.d. for the current computer?

Comment: @Tal : why would `Sys.info()['nodename']` not be sufficient? That should be unique on the network. Only other thing I can think of is using system() to fetch the MAC address, but that's highly system dependent.

Comment: Hi Joris, great idea.  I am interested in the unique i.d. for some ideas I've had with customizing my R/dropbox experience.  Your solution seems to do it (using system("ipconfig")).  Thanks!

Comment: @Tal Check also `Sys.getenv()` which gives you environmental variables.